# Microsoft Access 03 right click disabled or (ShortCut menu = no)

Tags: ms-access

I've been given an old access 03 mdb to fix after it keeps corrupting, in the mean time I fix it by using a year old backup and moving the data across from a view of a previous version.

Reason I have to use a view is because it's corrupt if I open the file normally and corrupt if I copy a view which works.

Back to the reason behind this topic, I need to get access to the database repair/compact tools to see if I can fix it once and for all that way along with seeing if it's some of the data which is corrupting it.

Right now the only menu options available are File, Window and Help and I can't right click either so since a couple different searchs for a fix have yet to yield anything I hope someone here might know of a way to solve this which I'd greatly appreciate.

Edit:
Forgot to add I've also checked all macro's and the single module and nothing indicates why tools is hidden or right click disabled and I can't find where I get access too (ShortCut menu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> while opening the database to get all options and bypass startup commands.

Comment: thx this is gona be so useful with dealing with these old projects, I've still yet to find exactly what they did to disable those menu options from start-up but since your answer does basically resolve the issue then I'm marking it as correct.

Comment: When you open the db with shift, have a look at "Tools > Startup" in the menu bar. They probably disabled the options there.

Comment: Yeh I had found that to be where the issue was with "Allow Full Menus" and "Allow Default Shortcut Menus" unticked. Ah well soon I'll prob be rewriting this db and making it a web app, then I'll never have to look at access again I hope.